# "Object Required" error when calling another form's sub

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to call a form Private Sub from another form, and when I run it I'm getting `Run-time error 424: Object Required`. The erroring code is the `Call frm_Main.add_arg(filt_key, filt)` at the end of:

```
Private Sub btn_go_to_pat_Click()

Dim filt_key As String
Dim filt As String

filt_key = "cont_hist_filter"
filt = "MRN = " & Me.MRN

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Main"
Call frm_Main.add_arg(filt_key, filt)

End Sub
```

The target sub is:

```
Public Sub add_arg(arg_key As String, arg_value As String)

MsgBox "Received arg_key " & arg_key & " with value " & arg_value

my_args.Add arg_key, arg_value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the form class is `Form_<form name>`, as you see it in the Project Explorer in the VBE.

So you need

```
Call Form_frm_Main.add_arg(filt_key, filt)
```

or

```
Dim fMain As Form_frm_Main
Set fMain = Forms!frm_Main
Call fMain.add_arg(filt_key, filt)
```

Comment: Both of those options return `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`, even if I put it in a `With` block.

Comment: That's probably for `my_args.Add`. Please see [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) @Rominus